# JavaScript unexpected token syntax error

Tags: javascript

What might be causing this error?
My code:

```
var a = ()
var s = 0
if (a == s) {
    console.log('in')
}
```

The error:

> SyntaxError { "Unexpected token" (1:23) }

Comment: What line does the error refer to?

Comment: @ScottHunter I assume the first one.

Comment: My answer assumes that you are trying to set `var a` to an empty list

Comment: yes, the first one

Comment: FF says: "_SyntaxError: expected expression, got ')'_". That means `var a = ()` causes the error. What is `()` supposed to be here? An array? An object? Something else?

Comment: a syntax error, of course.

Comment: Interesting how the answer with -2 score gets the correct answer rather than the answer with 2

Comment: both were useful i just found Guillaume's answer to be more complete since they analyzed how there wasn t any case in which it would make sense to have () there

Comment: @Guillaume Scheshank's answer is based on an assumption, which might be wrong ..?

Comment: @Teemu ok i get it

Comment: @KevinB Actually it's interesting, why an empty expression is a syntax error. Perhaps because it's hard to type under the hood?

Comment: i mean... it's not even an empty expression, it's the lack of one

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
var a = [];
var s = 0;
if (a == s) {
    console.log('in');
}
```

> **Why is this being caused?** - The characters `()` right now don't match the syntax of any normal use case of parenthesis. The ways to use parenthesis are here:

- define a function: `var a = function() { console.log("foo")}`
- call a function: `var a = Math.random(1)`
- define an arrow function: `var a = () => console.log("foo")`
- wrap any kind of expression: `var a = (true && false)`

Since in your code's syntax doesn't fit any of those it is giving a Syntax error.

The code above makes the code work using `[]`. `[]` creates an empty

Comment: semicolons are optional

Comment: @chiliNUT Yes but they are good practice

Comment: good practice is subjective.

Comment: fine lol @joeln

Comment: @joelnet The subjectiveness ends at a point where semicolon really is mandatory.

Comment: And it may become mandatory.

Comment: @DaveNewton seems like it would break a whole whole lot of old code if it did

Comment: @chiliNUT Yup. https://www.theregister.co.uk/AMP/2018/01/12/javascript_technical_group_semicolons/ It's not quite as sire as it may sound.